# Invariants of the group algebra of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups, invariant-theory

Consider a finite group $G$ and its complex group algebra $V_G$, on which $G$ acts. I would like to know: what are the polynomial $G$-invariants of $V_G$ i.e., the polynomial functions $p\in \mathbb{C}[V_G]$ that are $G$-invariant? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Are you asking for the polynomial invariants of the regular action of $G$, i.e. the linear group $G$ acting on $V_G$?

Comment: Yes, $V_G$ is the regular representation of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a particular case of rings of invariants of permutation groups. The $n=|G|$ elementary symmetric polynomials $\sigma_k$ form a system of parameters for $R:=\mathbb{C}[V_G]^G$, the ring in question, and $R$ is a free module of  rank $(n-1)!$ over the  subring generated by the $\sigma_k$.

See Sect. 2.7 of B.Sturmfels' "Algorithms in invariant theory", ISBN 978-3-211-77416-8, for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What about cyclic groups or in general finite Abelian groups? Is there a known answer in this case?

Comment: there is a discussion in the book I referred to. I don't  think there is an explicit answer known.